# How to set up Chrome driver for Selenium Grid 2 (Perl binding)?

Tags: perl, google-chrome, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to set up Selenium Grid 2 (Ubuntu-host for hub and Perl installed and Windows-host for various browsers (Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera)). Everything works fine, I can start short sample test against IE, FF, Opera and see how browser is open and page is loaded. Here is the test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Test::More tests=>4;

my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver -> new(
    'browser_name'  => 'internet explorer'
);
$driver->get("http://www.google.com");
$driver->quit();
```

But I can't make Chrome to work. I started Selenium-server with custom driver option on **Windows-host** (is this correct?) with

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.22.0.jar -role node -hub http://my-ubuntu-host:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome,version=19" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="c:\selenium-2-22-0\chromedriver.exe"
```

And when I attempt to run a test on **Ubuntu-host** with `'browser_name'  => 'chrome'` it only reports short error-message:

```
caligula@my-ubuntu-host:~/www$ ./test.pl 
1..4
Could not create new session at ./test.pl line 5.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.
```

Can somebody assist me with this? There are a lot of examples, but they are all in Java and I couldn't accommodate any of them to Perl code.

Also I noticed that chrome driver archive was named **chromedriver_win_20.0.1133.0.zip**. Is it compatible with **selenium server 2.22** ? I've tried to use selenium server 2.20 but then nothing worked at all: nor FF, nor IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Required parameter `'proxy' => {HASH}` was not passed to the constructor. Only chrome-driver throws an exception, whereas when you call FF or IE everything is fine.

There was short message in console:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: proxy must be of type dictionary, not null.
Received: null
```

creating `Selenium::Remote::Driver` instance in the following way solved the problem:

```
    my $driver = new Selenium::Remote::Driver(
        'browser_name' => 'chrome',
        'proxy' => {
            'proxyType' => 'system'
        }
    );
```